# Listening to JComboBoxes and JTextFields to modify activate Class Mutators

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have a little form in a Swing GUI that once the object is change I want to call some custom mutators to my class but I just can't figure out how to fetch that info and call my mutators. Here is the relevant code, I know this is relatively simple but I just cant figure it out.

For reference namebox's content when changed or lost focus should call .setName(String x)
genderbox's content when changed or lost focus should call .setGender(Boolean x)
racebox's content when changed or lost focus should call .setRace(int a) where a is the index number of the array used to build the form
classbox's functions identically to Racebox

update: Found some of what i need,  i needed a label for the items and then use getsource, and getActioCommand but while that should work for Most aspects i still have a small problem the Genderbox stores a string but i want it to have a int value and only display a string is there a way with a j combo box to set a value and a display option text seperatly?

```
    JTextField namebox = new JTextField(nala.getName());
    namebox.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    //Create the combo box for gender.
    String[] gender = { "male", "female" };
    JComboBox genderBox = new JComboBox(gender);
    if (nala.getGender()){genderBox.setSelectedIndex(1);}else{genderBox.setSelectedIndex(0);}
    genderBox.addActionListener(this);
    genderBox.setActionCommand("GenderBox");

    //Create the combo box for race.
    String[] cRace = new String[75];
    for (int i=0; i<75; i++){cRace[i] = nala.getRaceName(i);}
    JComboBox raceBox = new JComboBox(cRace);
    raceBox.setSelectedIndex((int)nala.getRace());
    raceBox.addActionListener(this);

    //Create the combo box for class.
    String[] cClass = new String[50];
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++){cClass[i] = nala.getClassName(i);}
    JComboBox classBox = new JComboBox(cClass);
    classBox.setSelectedIndex((int)nala.getRace());
    classBox.addActionListener(this);

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("GenderBox")){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(cb.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
         JLabel label = new JLabel(setStatsInfo());
    }//actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

Comment: You're not showing what I think may be the key code, your ActionListener code.

Comment: ActionListener is blank, because I'm complety at a loss on what to do to fetch the info and call set***() on that data

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) What is your question?

Comment: well my question is basicly "i dont understand actionlistener and have no idea how to start let alone use the lisister to call a mutator method."

Comment: ok after talking to my professor and looking around the interwebs i seem to have found most of what i need to find...updating main question to reflect that and clarify my problem

Comment: think i solved this problem with the above code i jsut have a different problem now sin this topic doesn't make sense, THANKS everyone though

Answer (score 2):

When there is selection change in the JComboBox use [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html).

**Example:**

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
  // TODO: Action.
  }
});
```

Your code shows only adding of the `listeners` which does give any clue to your problem. Please post the `ActionEvent` method code to show us the problem.